# How to fix the confusion in the combination of Persian letters and numbers

Tags: python, farsi

Well, the problem is that the combination of Persian letters and numbers in the output of my script looks like this:
456b123

If it should be like this:
123B456

Note :For those who do not know the Persian language format,In Persian, letters are written from right to left and numbers from left to right

```
with open("output/mojaz1.csv", "r",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as mojaz:
                        reader = csv.reader(mojaz)
                        mojazha = list(reader)
                        print(mojazha)
```

output:۹۷ج۴۶۱۷۷ ...

oh god! I have this typing problem here too and I can't continue

os:windows
python :3.6.13
I did not have this problem in Linux, but it is in Windows

Comment: Let's look more sample inputs?

Comment: more details, please?

Comment: Handling text direction is **far** too broad of a topic for a Stack Overflow post. Unicode's system for it is [very complicated](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/), especially when you have to embed text from other languages.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there are still many problems in the Unicode system for the Persian language. Is there a way for me to define Unicode for my script?

Answer (score 0):

there is a character named RTL Embedding, with Unicode of U+202B,
to copy it use [Right-To-Left Embedding](https://unicode-table.com/en/202B/).

put it before the text and the paragraph becomes right to left, or add a [U+202A character](https://unicode-table.com/en/202A/) and everything is again back to left to right.

let's compare two texts here, the first one is plain, the second one has U+202B in the beginning:

نمونه!

vs

‫نمونه!

up to now it was all about the paragraph but what about texts within a paragraph? here we use [U+200F](https://unicode-table.com/en/200F/) character to align the text to right to left, and [U+200E](https://unicode-table.com/en/200E/) to align it back to left to right.

here are two examples, the first one is plain and the second one has U+200F in the beginning:

۱۲۳نمونه۴۵۶

vs

‏۱۲۳نمونه۴۵۶

and also, to make the text ۱۲۳نمونه‎۴۵۶ add [U+200E](https://unicode-table.com/en/200E/) before the second series of numbers (۴۵۶)

‫موفق باشی!